# How to get another user's details using RestFB?

Tags: restfb

Can anyone suggest me for the below mentioned query?

I am able to get the our own profile details using restFB API like post.
**Is it possible to get another user's or friend's details using restFB? I have user's unique id.**

Answer (score 0):

Using the user id as "endpoint" you can get the user's public information. With graph api 2.4 you need the fields parameter.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user